# How to clip buffer polygon from its source line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, clip

I'm trying to clip a 30 meter buffer polygon built around a highway line feature using a smaller 6 meter buffer that represents the actual width of the road, so that the original 30  meter buffer is actually 6 meters away from the highway line feature it was created from.

This is so I can calculate slope and land cover, etc., on the edge of the road without including the road itself.

Whenever I try this, it just clips the 30 meter buffer down to 6 meters.

Is it possible to clip a buffer off of its source feature in this way?

Comment: What Software are you using?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what you're trying to do.  Perhaps an image would help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, FYI, or rather I found the answer on ESRI help page:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000002w000000

Clip the inner buffer in an editing session rather than with the Clip tool.